# Recent changed Locations in vscode (Like in IntelliJ)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I like the feature [Recent Locations](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tips/recent-locations/) of IntelliJ.

[image: pycharm-recent-locations]

For other reasons I will use vscode (for golang).

Is there a similar feature in vscode?

I want to see a list of the my recent locations (optional filtered, so that only the locaions are visible, which where recently changed).

After a break (like lunch), this feature is really handy. It helps you to connect to your work before the break.

**Especially the "show changed only" is very helpful.**

Comment: FWIW, one could _probably_ write an extension to do this. just a matter of putting in the legwork. don't look at me though :P

Answer (score 2):

If you use git, you get most of what you request here. Vscode has a git extension in the sidebar that shows you what files you have changed, as in unstaged and staged changes.

You can also jump between location, with `alt+left/right` arrow. This is independent from git. It just remembers your last cursor positions.

If you are willing to use an extension, there is one that seems to do what you are asking for, judging by its name: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=percygrunwald.vscode-intellij-recent-files

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know git and I know `alt+left/right`. Both don't give me this handy list of recent locations.

Comment: The extension behavior is almost identical to intelliJ's quick open.

Comment: @EnriqueGonzález the above question is about the **recent locations** feature of Intellij. The vscode plugin vscode-intellij-recent-files does show files. It would be great to have a plugin which shows the recent **locations**. See screenshot in question.

Comment: @guettli, 100% agreement, this extension fundamentally does not provide the recent locations behaviour. Really frustration :/

Answer (score 2):

This function is called "navigate Back", you find it also in the [Key Bindings for Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/keybindings) and more accessible within vscode from the keybindings UI.

[image]

Comment: I am missing a way to get a list of all the locations I recently **edited**.

Answer (score 1):

@guettli They are different editors, so it will be hard to always find the exact same feature. I think there is nothing like recent locations in vsCode, at least when i'm writing this. Will there be something like that in the future? Probably.

Ctrl-P will display a list of recently opened files, and by selecting one of the files it will go to the last location when editing the file. To see the changes in a file(w/ git) you can right-click it and select the "view timeline" or view the changes with the git button. Not exactly what you asked for but may be useful.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think I will miss "recent locations", especially "recent changed locations" (ctrl-shift-e twice) from Intellij a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+P will display a list of recently opened files in Vscode
[image: Ctrl+p gives recent opened/changed files list]

You can use Timeline option at the right-bottom corner of the vscode for comparing previous file and current changes of the file that is in currently opened

[image: You can see i opened Index.html file, the changes i made before and after for the same file]

You can even compare the files with options on right clicking the file
[image: Right click on timeline opened file to see the options]

You can get more about code navigations in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MuQmMsIpI04

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I know the above solutions you provided. I search for a list of recent locations which spans several files. See the screenshot of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the [Gitlens extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) and I use the shortcut `"ctrl+shift+g g"` for the command `workbench.view.scm` to quickly see the files modified since the last commit and navigate among them.
[image]

Comment: thank you for trying it. This has two drawbacks: If I committed just a second ago, then the list is empty, and I don't see my recent changes. Or if have a lot of uncommitted changes, then the list will be huge, and not sorted by "recently changed".

Comment: To quickly navigate in the recent changes, I use the commands "Go Back" and "Go Forward" (I have these commands bind on "alt+right" and "alt+left"). It works even after a commit.